# Express routing confusion

Tags: express

I have the following endpoint to access my session's instances:

```
<base-url>/sessions/<id>
```

I tried to catch the requests to this endpoint using the following line:

```
router.patch("/sessions/:id", tryLogout);
```

I can see in the browser that the correct endpoint is used:

```
<base-url>/sessions/117
```

However, express returns 404-

When I now add the * at the end:

```
router.patch("/sessions/:id*", tryLogout);
```

it works fine. This soution does not suit me, because it will also match endpoint like /sessions/111/user, and that's not the point.

How can I fix this and catch only what I need to catch?

**UPDATE:**

I little update after a comment.
I tried to simplify the question, but maybe there is a problem. I'm using two levels of express routers.

In the main web server app:

```
var app = express();
app.use("/api/admin", admin_router);   // this should sent all the admin-requests to a subrouter admin_router
```

Relevant (working) code from admin_router:

```
var router = express();
router.patch("/sessions/:id*", tryLogout);  // sends 404 without the *
```

On the frontend side, I use the Backbone models to send the request. Relevant pieces of code:

```
...Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: "api/admin/sessions",

        idAttribute: "id",

        logout: function(callback) {
            var attr = {
                // sets the atts here
            }

            this.save(attr,{
                patch: true,
                success: function(data) {
                    callback(null, data)
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    // error handling
                }
            });
        }   // logout()
```

Comment: It works for me in a [simple example](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/84d068992e438203fc77). How are you using the router exactly? Do you use `app.param()` perhaps?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I'm not even using it at that point, it does not match. I usee router.patch, just like shown.

Comment: Possible reasons it doesn't match: you're not using the `PATCH` method for your request (not likely, otherwise the `*` wouldn't have made a difference), you're not setting the base URL properly, you're using `app.param()` to validate `:id` parameters and there's an issue there, you're using strict routing and accidently are adding a slash at the end, there's middleware causing problems. And there are probably more...

Comment: I will make a little update over there to answer this (actually, there are 2 routers)